# Want to print full Array.asList , Only printing one line

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Application in Android Studio to that prints how many of each item you can buy with the given amount of currency. It printed flawlessly when run as a Java program in Eclipse but I can not get it to print more than one line in the TextView Box.

I've noticed it will pick the most Expensive item you can afford 1 of and print it alone, leading me to believe it runs through the list and only prints the last one that passes as affordable. I've read about needing to use a StringBuilder and such but have found little information on how to convert my `Array.asList` over to this. Here is my code.

```
gCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText diamondInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.diamondInput);

            try {
                int diamonds = Integer.parseInt(diamondInput.getText().toString());
                List<Gifts> gift = Arrays.asList(new Gifts[]{new Gifts("Gold star", 10), new Gifts("Love Bear", 10), new Gifts("Lillies", 10), new Gifts("Box Of Chocolate", 20), new Gifts("Taco", 20), new Gifts("Thumbs Up", 30), new Gifts("Panda", 40), new Gifts("Beer", 40), new Gifts("Patriot", 52), new Gifts("Eagle", 52), new Gifts("Gold Chain", 80), new Gifts("Roses", 100), new Gifts("Champagne", 100), new Gifts("Snow", 100), new Gifts("Candy", 100), new Gifts("Kiss", 200), new Gifts("Candy Hearts", 250), new Gifts("Peach", 300), new Gifts("EggPlant", 300), new Gifts("Fireworks", 500), new Gifts("GemDrop", 600), new Gifts("Crown", 600), new Gifts("Cupcakes", 700), new Gifts("Heart Balloon", 800), new Gifts("Sports Car", 1000), new Gifts("Smoke Rings", 1000), new Gifts("purple Diamond", 2500), new Gifts("Cupid", 5000), new Gifts("Gold Watch", 5000), new Gifts("Castle", 5000), new Gifts("Yacht", 10000), new Gifts("Jet", 20000)});


                double coins = (double) diamonds / 2.5D;
                Iterator var5 = gift.iterator();

                while(var5.hasNext()) {
                    Gifts Gifts = (Gifts)var5.next();
                    int qty = (int)Gifts.getQty(coins);
                        if(qty > 0) {
                        result.setText("You can buy " + qty + " " + Gifts.name);
                                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // friendly error to the user: field is incorrect
            }
```

I need it to print as this EX:

You can buy X amount of Y
 You can buy X amount of Y
 You can buy X amount of Y
  :end
 Printing every item that can be bought and it's quantity.

Comment: Why do you think `result.setText(..)` _appends_ to the text already in there?

Comment: looks like you are overriding textview's text ,anyway use a recycler view or list view for this type of functionality

Comment: @Tom That's not much of an Explanation as much as a sarcastic remark.

Comment: What kind of explanation do you want? The word ["set"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set) in `setText` makes it pretty clear, that it sets the text (replacing the old one), not append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into Android API documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) , this is what it states:

`void setText (CharSequence text)` - ***sets*** the text to be displayed. - this means that each time you call this method, new text overrides the old one.

It seems that you are looking for `append()` method:

`void append(CharSequence text)` - *convenience method to **append** the specified text to the TextView's display buffer, upgrading it to EDITABLE if it was not already editable.* `append()` method doesn't override previously set text.

Another way to append text to the previously stored in `TextView` is to combine these methods:

```
result.setText(result.getText() + "text that you want to append to the previous one")
```